# How can I always show the popup on my jquery mobile slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have a slider in jquery mobile with two handles:

```
<div data-role="rangeslider" data-mini="true;">
    <label for="range-1a" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;">Dates:</label>
    <input name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="1994" max="2015" value="1994" type="range" onchange="chk()" data-popup-enabled="true"/>
    <label for="range-1b">Rangeslider:</label>
    <input name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="1994" max="2015" value="2015" type="range" onchange="chk()" data-popup-enabled="true"/>
</div>
```

by adding the attribute:

```
data-popup-enabled="true"
```

I'm able to create a nice popup when a user clicks on the slider handle:

[image]

However, I want to display this popup all the time instead of only on-click. I've attempted to remove the display:none css property without any luck:

```
$(".ui-slider-popup").css("display", "");
```

I also want the textboxes at the ends to be static. That way the user knows the range they have and the constant popup with show what they've selected. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the popup appear at all times, I've added the following CSS:

```
.ui-slider-popup {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Also to override any styles applied to the popup via jQuery, you can simply type in the style property followed by `!important` like I've done above.

Moreover, to make the input fields static, you can use the `readonly` attribute inside the `<input>` tag, here's your revised HTML structure:

```
<div data-role="rangeslider" data-mini="true;">
    <label for="range-1a" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 15px;">Dates:</label>
    <input name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="1994" max="2015" value="1994" type="range" onchange="chk()" data-popup-enabled="true" readonly />
    <label for="range-1b">Rangeslider:</label>
    <input name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="1994" max="2015" value="2015" type="range" onchange="chk()" data-popup-enabled="true" readonly />
</div>
```

Here's a **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6rnsqjkL/11/)**.

Comment: thanks for the response. I guess I wasn't too clear when I meant 'static'. I want the end textboxes to always show the end numbers even after I move the slider. So the end textboxes would always show 1994 and 2015. Would this be possible? I was thinking of even creating my own static textbox and place them over the current boxes.

Comment: @RDoolabhI don't think doing that would be possible since there's no available attribute to disable that, here are all the available attributes: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/range#HTML_Attributes

Comment: @RDoolabh Here's something that I've coded which you can use in the meantime: http://jsfiddle.net/6rnsqjkL/27/. Since you can't simply make the values static, this solution is just a workaround of how you want it to function. Hope it helps.